# Use multiple subscription in a single Azure Power shell command

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I am using following command :

```
Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionID
Set-AzureRmSqlDatabaseAuditingPolicy -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ServerName $servername -DatabaseName $dbServer.DatabaseName -StorageAccountName $storageAccount
```

Storage Account and DB server belong to different subscriptions , how can I execute a command that will allow to access resources from multiple subscription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I execute a command that will allow to access resources from
>   multiple subscription

We can share your resource groups to different subscriptions, to achieve this, we should **invite** user B(subscription 2) to AAD (subscription 1), and grant resource group permission to user B, then we can use PowerShell to get the resource groups.
[image]

Here a similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45413631/manage-debug-virtual-machines-on-someone-elses-azure-subscription/45432496#45432496) about you, please refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following command to select subscription :-

```
az account set --subscription "Subscription Name or Subscription Id"
```

[image: Image of Azure multiple subscription]